# unable to ping host aft.ing 14.04 to 16.04 server

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have updated ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 server and once updated, I am unable to ping host, but 8.8.8.8 is pinging. There is no `/etc/resolv.conf` file available to update.